Approach to bind websites hosted at 2 different places under single domain
Main domain is hosted at Route53. Main website is hosted at WPEngine. The main page has 3 links on the menubar, say About/Products/Blog. When I click Products, I want the site to show domain.com/products on the address bar but serve the content from a S3 hosted public website. I can think of using Nginx in an EC2 and proxying the traffic but is there any better approach to achieve this use case?
